# Server Error in '/' in my asp.net mvc application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am getting this Error in my application:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Parser Error 
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'BeneFactReporting.BAReports.Index'.

Source Error: 

Line 1:  <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/BAReports/BAReportSite.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Index.aspx.cs" Inherits="BeneFactReporting.BAReports.Index" %>
Line 2:  <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
Line 3:  </asp:Content>


Source File: /BAReports/Index.aspx    Line: 1 


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.237
```

I have two Applications one is BeneFactReporting and other one is NascoBuilder

I just added BeneFactReporting.dll in to NascoBuilder application. when I ran the application I am getting this error. I am not understanding why i am getting this error.

Pleasee can any body help me out with this error.

Thanks

Comment: CodeBehind? In an ASP.NET MVC view? Why?

Comment: why are you using masterpages in an MVC application anyway?

Comment: Might he scrambled two technologies together ?

Comment: @IamStalker Mmmm, scrambled technologies.  I prefer mine to be sunny side up.

Comment: @jadarnel27 - I find poached to be rather delightful, especially on a crisp Sunday morning

Comment: I am getting problem in the View.

Comment: I am not sure why the people are made -ve for my post.. this thing I am asking you guys that I dont know how to solve this problem. please consider  my questions.

Comment: Lol I love my to be scrambled with bacooon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm betting that it doesn't like the "CodeBehind" attribute in your @Page directive. MVC pages don't have code behind files.

If you've just copied a Webforms master page and are trying to use it with your MVC application, you're out of luck. If you've added a new master page to your MVC application, make sure you selected "MVC Master Page" when creating the file; a standard ASP.NET master page won't work in this context.